# How to convert a sample dataset from the R package "spatstat" into a shapefile

Tags: java, r, gis, shapefile

I have written a kernel density estimator in Java that takes input in the form of ESRI shapefiles and outputs a GeoTIFF image of the estimated surface.  To test this module I need an example shapefile, and for whatever reason I have been told to retrieve one from the sample data included in R.  Problem is that none of the sample data is a shapefile...

So I'm trying to use the shapefiles package's funciton `convert.to.shapefile(4)` to convert the bei dataset included in the spatstat package in R to a shapefile.  Unfortunately this is proving to be harder than I thought.  Does anyone have any experience in doing this?  If you'd be so kind as to lend me a hand here I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Ryan

References:
[spatstat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/spatstat.pdf),
[shapefiles](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/shapefiles/html/shapefiles.html)

Comment: Why the `bei` dataset in particular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are converter functions for `Spatial` objects in the `spatstat` and `maptools` packages that can be used for this. A shapefile consists of at least points (or lines or polygons) and attributes for each object.

```
library(spatstat)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
data(bei)
```

Coerce `bei` to a `Spatial` object, here just points without attributes since there are no "marks" on the `ppp` object.

```
spPoints <- as(bei, "SpatialPoints")
```

A shapefile requires at least one column of attribute data, so create a dummy.

```
dummyData <- data.frame(dummy = rep(0, npoints(bei)))
```

Using the `SpatialPoints` object and the dummy data, generate a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.

```
spDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(spPoints, dummyData)
```

At this point you should definitely consider what the coordinate system used by `bei` is and whether you can represent that with a `WKT CRS` (well-known text coordinate reference system). You can assign that to the `Spatial` object as another argument to `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, or after create with `proj4string(spDF) <- CRS("+proj=etc...")` (but this is an entire problem all on its own that we could write pages on).

Load the `rgdal` package (this is the most general option as it supports many formats and uses the GDAL library, but may not be available because of system dependencies.

```
library(rgdal)
```

(Use `writePolyShape` in the `maptools` package if `rgdal` is not available).

The syntax is the object, then the "data source name" (here the current directory, this can be a full path to a .shp, or a folder), then the layer (for shapefiles the file name without the extension), and then the name of the output driver.

```
writeOGR(obj = spDF, dsn = ".", layer = "bei", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Note that the write would fail if the "bei.shp" already existed and so would have to be deleted first `unlink("bei.shp")`.

List any files that start with "bei":

```
list.files(pattern = "^bei")

[1] "bei.dbf" "bei.shp" "bei.shx"
```

Note that there is no general "as.Spatial" converter for `ppp` objects, since decisions must be made as to whether this is a point patter with marks and so on - it might be interesting to try writing one, that reports on whether dummy data was required and so on.

See the following vignettes for further information and details on the differences between these data representations:

library(sp); vignette("sp")
library(spatstat); vignette("spatstat")

Comment: heh, first time I just threw the code out there so I've now added commentary to explain some things

Comment: Thank you to both responders, your solutions should work... my only problem is I am running this on Mac OS X, which isn't supported by rgdal.  I'll try and find a windows machine in my office to test these on this afternoon.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

A general solution is:

- convert the `"ppp"` or `"owin"` classed objects to appropriate classed objects from the `sp` package
- use the `writeOGR()` function from package `rgdal` to write the Shapefile out

For example, if we consider the `hamster` data set from `spatstat`:

```
require(spatstat)
require(maptools)
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
data(hamster)
```

first convert this object to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object:

```
ham.sp <- as.SpatialPointsDataFrame.ppp(hamster)
```

This gives us a `sp` object to work from:

```
> str(ham.sp, max = 2)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 303 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..@ coords.nrs : num(0) 
  ..@ coords     : num [1:303, 1:2] 6 10.8 25.8 26.8 32.5 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 0 0 250 250
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
```

This object has a single variable in the `@data` slot:

```
> head(ham.sp@data)
     marks
1 dividing
2 dividing
3 dividing
4 dividing
5 dividing
6 dividing
```

So say we now want to write out this variable as an ESRI Shapefile, we use `writeOGR()`

```
writeOGR(ham.sp, "hamster", "marks", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

This will create several `marks.xxx` files in directory `hamster` created in the current working directory. That set of files is the *ShapeFile*.

One of the reasons why I didn't do the above with the `bei` data set is that it doesn't contain any data and thus we can't coerce it to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` object. There *are* data we could use, in `bei.extra` (loaded at same time as `bei`), but these extra data or on a regular grid. So we'd have to

- convert `bei.extra` to a `SpatialGridDataFrame` object (say `bei.spg`)
- convert `bei` to a `SpatialPoints` object (say `bei.sp`)
- `overlay()` the `bei.sp` points on to the `bei.spg` grid, yielding values from the grid for each of the points in `bei`
- that should give us a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` that can be written out using `writeOGR()` as above

As you see, that is a bit more involved just to give you a Shapefile. Will the `hamster` data example I show suffice? If not, I can hunt out my [Bivand et al](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Applied-Spatial-Data-Analysis-Use/dp/0387781706/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1303853245&sr=1-2) tomorrow and run through the steps for `bei`.